# Multicolumn + multirow + minitab: vertical lines

Tags: multirow, multicolumn

In my table, I am using a `multirow` + `multicolumn` section to create a "merged" cell. However, I am running into an issue where the column borders bleed into that merged area. I provide an example with output below: is there an easy fix to remove the border overlapping A and B, while still keeping it for future rows? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{A} \\ \textbf{B}}}} & a \\
& & b \\
& & c \\ \hline
d & e & f \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since using a `multicolumn` environment overrides the `tabular` column definition, you simply need to specify a `multicolumn` for each of the "merged" rows you want. The modified code is below; note the two extra `multicolumn`s replacing the two `& &` .

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c | c | c}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{A} \\ \textbf{B}}}} & a \\
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & b \\
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & c \\ \hline
d & e & f\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: LaTeX output]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this does not work if there is another row below with distinct columns and where I would like to keep the vertical lines...

Comment: @antoinef Then please be more specific in your question: people can only answer what's being asked. If you intend to have more rows, will they follow the same format with the `multicolumn`? Or will they eventually be split into individual columns again?

Comment: sure. I have edited the original question.

Comment: @antoinef I edited my answer.